# ffmpeg how convert audio files in other formats?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I download audio file and me need convert him on formats .mp3,.wav,.ogg.,acc.
My script:

```php
if($ext=='wav'){
    shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $infile -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320 $outfile_mp3");
    shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $infile -acodec libvorbis -ab 320 $outfile_ogg");
    shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $infile -acodec libfaac -ab 320 $outfile_aac");
}
elseif($ext=='mp3'){
    shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $infile -ab 256 $outfile_wav");
    shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $infile -ab 256 $outfile_ogg");
    shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $infile -ab 256 $outfile_aac");
    move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$name2.'mp3');
}
elseif($ext=='ogg'){
    shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $infile -acodec libmp3lame $outfile_mp3");
    shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $infile $outfile_wav");
    shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $infile -acodec libfaac $outfile_aac");
}
elseif($ext=='aac'){
    shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $infile -acodec libmp3lame $outfile_mp3");
    shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $infile -acodec libvorbis $outfile_ogg");
    shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $infile -acodec libmp3lame $outfile_wav");
}
```

Help me please convert files:

1. how convert file in format **.mp3** in formats .wav, .ogg, .acc
2. how convert file in format **.wav** in formats .mp3, .wav, .acc
3. how convert file in format **.ogg** in formats .mp3, .ogg, .acc
4. how convert file in format **.acc** in formats .mp3, .ogg, .wav

I want to get good sound quality audio files...

Comment: And, what are you getting now?

Comment: shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $infile -ab 256 $outfile_wav");

shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $infile -ab 256 $outfile_ogg");

shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $infile -ab 256 $outfile_aac");

not conver original file to need formats((

Comment: I checked all the directories are correct

Comment: shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $infile -ab 256 $outfile_aac"); not create good file(bad file with size 0 kb).

Comment: Make sure your ffmpeg commands work, and then attempt to script it. If you see the ffmpeg console output it will probably tell you why the file is "bad". Also, ffmpeg uses bits as a value for `-ab`, so you'll want to change `-ab 320` to `-ab 320k` and same for 256.

Comment: Also, show us the complete ffmpeg console output!

Comment: i give:

FFmpeg version SVN-r12216, Copyright (c) 2000-2008 Fabrice Bellard, et al. configuration: libavutil version: 49.6.0 libavcodec version: 51.50.1 libavformat version: 52.7.0 libavdevice version: 52.0.0 built on Feb 25 2008 12:40:30, gcc: 4.1.2 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14)

Comment: invalid new backstep 1008 Input #0, mp3, from '/hsphere/local/home/c292729/testwork.ru/10001/ConcertMedia/1348165273ExPRoG.mp3': Duration: 00:01:48.8, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 319 kb/s Stream #0.0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, 320 kb/s Output #0, adts, to '/hsphere/local/home/c292729/testwork.ru/10001/ConcertMedia/1348165273ExPRoG.aac': Stream #0.0: Audio: 0x0000, 44100 Hz, stereo, 64 kb/s Stream mapping: Stream #0.0 -> #0.0 Unsupported codec for output stream #0.0

Comment: SVN-r12216 is absolutely ancient! There is no reason to use something so old.

Answer (score 2):

**first** you need use '**2>&1**' in your code, example

```
shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $infile $outfile_wav 2>&1");
```

**second**, if you have error 'Unsupported codec for output stream' you need install libfaac.dll liblary for ffmpeg in your hosting.

Enjoy=)